Update one table based on highest record value in another table in postgreSQL
I have two tables (see below) in a postgreSQL database.
Table1 tracks all changes made to each ID (i.e. multiple rows per ID):
create table table1(id,record,name,data1,data2,data3)as values
 (1,1,'Dave',  1.2,55,1)
,(1,2,'David', 1.2,55,1)
,(2,1,'Sam',    .8,30,2)
,(3,1,'Jenn',   .9,28,2)
,(4,1,'Arthur',1.1,77,1)
,(5,1,'Jim',    .7,42,2)
,(5,2,'Jimmy',  .7,42,2)
,(5,3,'James',  .7,42,2)
,(6,1,'Sue',   1.3,32,2)
,(6,2,'Susan', 1.3,32,2);

Table2 contains only one row per ID:
create table table2(id,record,name,data1,data2,data3)as values
 (1,1,'Dave',  1.2,55,1)
,(2,1,'Sam',    .8,30,2)
,(3,1,'Jenn',   .9,28,2)
,(4,1,'Arthur',1.1,77,1)
,(5,2,'Jimmy',  .7,42,2)
,(6,1,'Sue',   1.3,32,2);

I need an SQL query to update Table2 based on the highest Record value for each ID in Table1 and also updating all other fields as well (data1, data2, data3 in this example).
These tables are just examples but my actual data has many columns, so I would like to use some sort of wild card to include all fields in the update.
Relatively new to SQL in postgreSQL but here is my attempt at getting the most recent record version returned, but not sure how to update Table2 from there. I have had a few attempts but nothing work so probably not worth posting that code.
  select * from
    Table1 t1
  where
    (ID,Record) in 
    (
      select
        ID,
        MAX(Record)
      from
        Table1 t1
      group by
        ID
     )

ExpectedResult:



id
record
name
data1
data2
data3




1
2
David
1.2
55
1


2
1
Sam
0.8
30
2


3
1
Jenn
0.9
28
2


4
1
Arthur
1.1
77
1


5
3
James
0.7
42
2


6
2
Susan
1.3
32
2



fiddle

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result. Also note that homework related questions are expected to show some extra effort.

Thanks for the feedback! Not sure I follow the homework related question comment, this is a task I'm working on at work (not a student) ... unless I'm missing the point here. But I will update the question now to show expected result which help with the solution. Thanks again, much appreciated.

@jarlh Question Updated

@Andrew15 Please paste data as text, not pictures. It's best if you provide input samples as create then insert, or create..as values statements that others can use directly to reproduce this.

@Zegarek okay I will update. Thanks for the feedback.

The best way to achieve this is with a cte that makes use of distinct on.  Something along the following lines:
with cte as 
(SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, record, name, data1, data2, data3
from table1 ORDER BY id, record desc)
UPDATE table2 t
SET record = cte.record, data1 = cte.data1, data2 = cte.data2, data3 = cte.data3
FROM cte 
WHERE cte.id = t.id;

What distinct on gives you, is the ability to limit the resultset to just one line per column (or columns) that you are interested in.  The order by, which must start with the columns in the distinct on, determines from the remaining data, what row is returned.  Ordering by record descending is therefore the same as getting that row which has the MAX(record) for that id.
The update simply joins the cte to the target table and updates the values accordingly.
I am afraid that I know of no shortcut, which will mean that you do not need to specify each column!
For future reference, please supply sample data by way of insert statements. It saves us having to do the work to test.

The CTE will return all the records, and therefore, it will not work.

@JitendraLoyal It does work.

@JitendraLoyal the cte does not return all the records, precisely because of the DISTINCT ON.  Use of this construct has significant performance benefits over using a sub-select with MAX

@JonathanWillcock While your use of distinct on is correct, the claim about performance won't always hold: demo. A minor nitpick is that you both forgot to update the name. Here's my take, if you care to take a look.

@JonathanWillcock - a follow up question for you. What if I had a record in Table1 that didn't exist in Table2, say id = 7. Is there a way to write the new record to Table2 in this query?

@Andrew15 None of the updates shown in this thread would update a row that's not in the updated table. The re-inserts shown in my and eshirvana's posts would add the missing row because they don't rely on anything being present in table2. It's also possible to run an upsert using a merge in PostgreSQL 15+ or a insert..on conflict do update in earlier versions - the latter requires an arbiter index.

Thanks @JonathanWillcock! I learnt DISTINCT ON in the process!!

As long as you have an adequate index on table1:
create index on table1(id,record);

Or even a covering index:
create index on table1(id,record)
   include(name,data1,data2,data3)
   with(fillfactor=100);--only if it's also static or low-traffic

You can use the subselect UPDATE syntax for high performance: it'll just pop the new values right off the top of the index.
demo at db<>fiddle
update table2
set (record,data1,data2,data3,name)
  = ( select record,data1,data2,data3,name 
      from table1
      where table1.id=table2.id
      order by record desc
      limit 1);

In this test on 250k rows it takes about 32ms, over 10x less compared to the alternatives using distinct on, max(record) and row_number()over() shown so far.



QUERY PLAN




Update on public.table2  (cost=0.00..2168.85 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=32.811..32.812 rows=0 loops=1)


->  Seq Scan on public.table2  (cost=0.00..2168.85 rows=1000 width=114) (actual time=0.038..23.540 rows=1000 loops=1)


Output: $1, $5, $2, $3, $4, (SubPlan 1 (returns $1,$2,$3,$4,$5)), table2.ctid


SubPlan 1 (returns $1,$2,$3,$4,$5)


->  Limit  (cost=0.42..2.15 rows=1 width=65) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1000)


Output: table1.record, table1.data1, table1.data2, table1.data3, table1.name


->  Index Scan Backward using table1_id_record_idx on public.table1  (cost=0.42..439.80 rows=254 width=65) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1000)


Output: table1.record, table1.data1, table1.data2, table1.data3, table1.name


Index Cond: (table1.id = table2.id)


Planning Time: 0.318 ms


Execution Time: 32.858 ms






id
record
name
data1
data2
data3




1
2
David
1.2
55
1


2
4
Sam_87c72ddd03ffb361376ea1bbba13e1ef
14.8233387496332
76
7


3
7
Jenn_10f9718be5ae1afb1d09b4e1876b8c73
1.56088112254495
141
1


4
8
Arthur_931cda9c0d7bd41f48c34da82630056f
1.54771245316149
156
13


5
17
Jimmy_f51ac03b548a1b97e21ddee65b541f6a
19.0104059532617
49
14


6
5
Sue_f27465110d40fd9e7cb9f8fb06ef90a7
18.0244532806921
52
18


7
375
13383e23_033795c92d8ff29e1591c31a5def602e
17.2182228592902
134
10


8
51
70a08605_177548ade65d5f17d0c24213b9a1eef5
4.34541311348988
47
15


9
451
67a7cdba_91f34d1829098bf884461e2f35e32ebc
12.395314480184
83
9


10
160
78412cd7_cea9d43c182b070a53f15d3597a056a0
3.33623168921786
22
16



If you want to be free from having to know the column names but you can trust the structures of table1 and table2 match, you can run a re-insert:
with cte as(delete from table2
--remove this `where` if you don't want to accumulate erased `table1.id`s
            where id in(select id from table1))
insert into table2 
select*from table1
where(id,record)in(select id,max(record)
                   from table1
                   group by id);

And that can still use the index and finish up about 2x faster in around 160ms.
If you're suspecting some sort of inefficiency from the fact this wipes and re-writes the whole thing, don't. In Postgres MVCC every update is actually a delete+insert.



QUERY PLAN




Insert on public.table2  (cost=8484.71..14491.02 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=140.852..140.855 rows=0 loops=1)


CTE cte


->  Delete on public.table2 table2_1  (cost=0.42..1782.73 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=17.114..17.114 rows=0 loops=1)


->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.42..1782.73 rows=959 width=12) (actual time=0.024..16.310 rows=989 loops=1)


Output: table2_1.ctid, table1_2.ctid


->  Seq Scan on public.table2 table2_1  (cost=0.00..69.67 rows=3667 width=10) (actual time=0.015..0.354 rows=1000 loops=1)


Output: table2_1.ctid, table2_1.id


->  Index Scan using table1_id_record_idx on public.table1 table1_2  (cost=0.42..8.94 rows=256 width=10) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1000)


Output: table1_2.ctid, table1_2.id


Index Cond: (table1_2.id = table2_1.id)


->  Nested Loop  (cost=6701.97..12708.28 rows=271 width=69) (actual time=132.262..137.028 rows=989 loops=1)


Output: table1.id, table1.record, table1.name, table1.data1, table1.data2, table1.data3


->  HashAggregate  (cost=6701.55..6711.14 rows=959 width=8) (actual time=132.235..132.612 rows=989 loops=1)


Output: table1_1.id, max(table1_1.record)


Group Key: table1_1.id


Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 193kB


->  Seq Scan on public.table1 table1_1  (cost=0.00..5476.37 rows=245037 width=8) (actual time=0.008..18.027 rows=245037 loops=1)


Output: table1_1.id, table1_1.record, table1_1.name, table1_1.data1, table1_1.data2, table1_1.data3


->  Index Scan using table1_id_record_idx on public.table1  (cost=0.42..6.23 rows=1 width=69) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=989)


Output: table1.id, table1.record, table1.name, table1.data1, table1.data2, table1.data3


Index Cond: ((table1.id = table1_1.id) AND (table1.record = (max(table1_1.record))))


Planning Time: 0.340 ms


Execution Time: 158.030 ms




A fully detailed answer, +1

you can use row_number window function to get the latest record for each id like so :
with cte as (
 select * , row_number() over (partition by id order by record desc) as rn
  from table1
)

select * from cte where rn = 1




id
record
name
data1
data2
data3
rn




1
2
David
1.2
55
1
1


2
1
Sam
0.8
30
2
1


3
1
Jenn
0.9
28
2
1


4
1
Arthur
1.1
77
1
1


5
3
James
0.7
42
2
1


6
2
Susan
1.3
32
2
1



depending on how often you want to update table2 probably just truncate the table2 and insert these values in them each time.
fiddle

We get the maximum record for each ID in the CTE (hgh) and use that in the associated UPDATE statement to update the respective columns:
WITH hgh AS (
    SELECT  ID, MAX (Record) AS max_record
    FROM    Table1
    GROUP BY ID
)
UPDATE   Table2 t2
  SET Data1 = t1.Data1,
      Data2 = t1.Data2,
      Data3 = t1.Data3,
      Record = t1.Record
FROM hgh h
   JOIN Table1 t1
       ON (   t1.ID = h.ID
          AND t1.record = h.max_record
          )
WHERE  t2.ID = t1.ID

